# How to send some realtime logs to rails view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actioncable

I have a rails service that process some job. I want to send logs to view so user knows the current state of the process.

The view will have status indicator and log container.

Here's a sample view

```
Status: Running

**LOGS**
2017-02-27 10:00:00 - Job started..
2017-02-27 10:00:10 - Downloading some_file from server..
2017-02-27 10:00:40 - Download successfull..
2017-02-27 10:01:20 - Compressing file..
2017-02-27 10:01:52 - Sending file..
2017-02-27 10:02:02 - Job ended.
```

Answer (score 0):

The idea is background job will write log to temporary table. A javascript interval process will be performed at View in order to call to sever every 5 seconds to get new log records.
Let's see example:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    setInterval(refreshPartial, 5000)
  });
  function refreshPartial() {
    $.ajax({
      url: "#{'/writing_log/refresh_detai?filter_by=%s' % [params[:filter_by]]}"
    })
  }
```